# Substitution in Admonitions

Tags: documentation, python-sphinx, substitution, restructuredtext

How can I do a substitution in an admonition?

For example:

```
|p| account

.. note::

    **Been using |p| separately and now integrating?**
```

In my sphinx conf.py I define a replacement rule which gets appended to the rst file prior to interpretation (at least that is how I understand it):

```
rst_epilog = '.. |p| replace:: Labnext'
```

My first substitution in the paragraph works without fail.  However the substitution in the note directive isn't applied.  Any work arounds?

Thanks,

Mike

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The substitution in the note works if you remove the strong emphasis (double asterisks). Nesting of inline markup is not supported.

References:

- https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/basics.html#inline-markup
- http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/ref/rst/restructuredtext.html#inline-markup
- http://docutils.sourceforge.net/FAQ.html#is-nested-inline-markup-possible

---

Here is a workaround if you need to keep the strong emphasis:

1. In conf.py, use the following definition:

   ```
    rst_epilog = '.. |p| replace:: **Labnext**'
   ```
2. In your .rst file, use this markup:

   ```
    .. note::

      **Been using** |p| **separately and now integrating?**
   ```