# Nested substitutions in sphinx

Tags: python-sphinx, substitution, restructuredtext

I am creating my documentation in [Sphinx](http://sphinx-doc.org/) (I am learning the basics still). In my project there are some files with very long names and I refer to them in my document many times, so, to make my life easier, I decided to use substitutions like this:

```
.. |MyFile| replace:: a_very_very_long_name_for_a_file_v2.0.txt
```

And then I just type `|MyFile|` anywhere I want to refer to that file. That works just fine, but now I would like to make the version part variable, so I don't have to change all my aliases when I make a new release (I'm sure I would forget something). Luckily Sphinx sets the variable `version` so I tried:

```
.. |MyFile| replace:: a_very_very_long_name_for_a_file_v |version| .txt
```

But that nested replacement is ignored. I've been googling for more than an hour now and I am surprised no one has asked this before. I've seen something about Parsed Literals but I couldn't make it work. Make an alias based on other alias should be something quite common, right? Am I missing something? Is there a better approach for this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It works for me. Have you set `version` to 2.0 in conf.py?

Substitution definition:

```
.. |MyFile| replace:: a_very_very_long_name_for_a_file_v\ |version|\ .txt
```

Output when using the `|MyFile|` reference:

```
a_very_very_long_name_for_a_file_v2.0.txt
```

Note that the whitespaces before and after `|version|` are escaped in order to exclude them from the output (see http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/ref/rst/restructuredtext.html#escaping-mechanism).

Comment: Yes, I did. But thanks a lot because now I see that I was doing something stupid: I had: `.. |MyFile| replace:: **a_very_long_name_for_a_file_v\ |version|\ .txt**`. The * made the whole thing not work and if I remove them works just fine. I was going crazy and the problem was in front of me all the time. So, to finish this question, is there a way to use bold, italic etc in replacements?

Comment: Nested inline markup is hard. It is not really supported, but there are more or less ugly workarounds. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/24123141/407651 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/30996300/407651.