# How can I use Unicode characters in reStructuredText (reST)?

Tags: unicode, python-sphinx, restructuredtext

I need to use Unicode characters in my Sphinx documentation.

When I insert the line

```
.. |ohat| unicode:: U+00F4 .. ohat
```

at the top of a file, I get a `"ô"` only if the `"|ohat|"` is surrounded by space.

But if the `"|ohat|"` is inside a word, it is not translated - I get `"D|ohat|le"` instead of `"Dôle"`.

How can I use Unicode characters inside a word when using rst?

Comment: Can you not just use `Dôle` in the text?

Comment: I can't type the o hat on my keyboard. And it's not only this character i need to use.

Comment: All modern operating systems have some way of entering diacritics. On macOS, `option-I`, then `o`, renders `ô`.

Comment: This should work if you want to use a substitution: `D\ |ohat|\ le`. Similar questions: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27418207/407651, https://stackoverflow.com/a/34433397/407651

Comment: Taht's exactly what i need! Thanks. Perhaps you shoud make this an answer so i can upvote it?

Answer (score 2):

##### Without a substitution

Just use `Dôle` in the document.

##### With a substitution

The substitution reference must be surrounded by whitespace. In order to exclude the whitespace from the output, escaping is needed:

```
D\ |ohat|\ le
```

References:

- https://docutils.sourceforge.io/docs/ref/rst/restructuredtext.html#escaping-mechanism
- https://docutils.sourceforge.io/docs/ref/rst/restructuredtext.html#character-level-inline-markup-1

Answer (score 1):

With the :trim: option of the "[unicode](https://docutils.sourceforge.io/docs/ref/rst/directives.html#unicode-character-codes)" directive, you can define a substitution that removes surrounding whitespace:

```
.. |ohat| unicode:: U+00F4
   :trim:

D |ohat| le
```

prints "Dôle".

To get whitespace around the replacement character put escaped spaces around the substitution `D \ |ohat|\  le`. There are also the :ltrim: and :rtrim: options for one-sided trimming.

There are sets of *ready-made substitution definitions* in the [reStructuredText Standard Definition Files](https://docutils.sourceforge.io/docs/ref/rst/definitions.html).
This may be convenient, if you need several substitutions. E.g after

```
.. include:: <isolat1.txt>

you can write D\ |ocirc|\ le et no\ |euml|\ l.
```

(These definitions are without the "trim" option, so you need the escaped whitespace for occurences inside a word.)